# Deactivation of a WCF service

Tags: wcf

I some WCF services, which are hosted via WAS (and IIS 7). Is it possible to deactivate some selected services without uninstalling or removing them ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to deactivate them once they have been activated, so that they are no longer running?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove them (their endpoints) from your web.config.

If you don't expose any endpoints, no one can connect to your service.

Marc